# How to create a UriMatcher that can match mildy complex patterns?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make the UriMatcher match on something with two id's in it:

```
content://com.example.myapp/letters/lookup/87030b770a0f47b78d65b4254bdc0159/eeccdd496f414dd4a7875739f42df82f
```

I did the matcher like this:

```
URI_MATCHER.addURI(MyAppDataContract.AUTHORITY, "letters/lookup/*/*", LETTERS_BY_UNIQUE_ID);
```

In my app, the first id is the account_id and the second is a record id (UUID format)

It isn't matching.

Comment: And what's going wrong? It isn't matching?

Comment: Correct -- I amended the question.